# how to pass a char variable to FS_write() function -- EmFile?

Tags: c, char, parameter-passing

I`m trying to use EmFile library for embedded programing based on C.

this is the structure of FS_write in API documentation :

```
U32 FS_Write (FS_FILE * pFile,
              const void * pData,
              U32 NumBytes);
```

I want to write my own function for my later use like:

```
void SD_write_to_file(char buff)
{

    if(pFile)
    {

    if(0 != FS_Write(pFile, buff, strlen(buff))) 
    {

    }
    else
    {
        FontWrite_Position(100,148);//Text written to the position
        PutStringLCD("Failed to write data to file");
    }
    }
 }
```

the problem is that when I call this function and pass my char value, it can`t use it for FS_write. 
for example:

```
    sprintf(tempwordshow, "%f", realSamples[realsamplescounter]);

    SD_write_to_file(tempwordshow);
```

realSample[ ] is float and tempwordshow is char.

Note that if use the function like :

```
    if(0 != FS_Write(pFile, "0123456789", 10u))
```

it is working.

I think the problem is from the way of passing my data to this function .

any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, make sure functions which take a pointer as argument do indeed receiver pointers. And conversely if you intend to use a pointer, you should make sure the function's signature takes a pointer as argument.

In this particular case your intention seems to be to write a buffer of characters (which can be passed to a function by passing a pointer to the memory location corresponding to the buffer), which would in all likelyhoods be more than a single `char`. Correspondingly, the signature of the `SD_write_to_file` should be changed to:

```
  void SD_write_to_file(const char* buff)
```

You may have a similar problem with `sprintf`'s first argument is expected to be of type `char*` whereas you mention that `tempwordshow` is of type `char` (note also that there should be memory allocated wherever `tempwordshow` points to). If it wasn't a trivial typo in your question, then you would have to convert `tempwordshow`'s declaration to something such as:

```
  char tempwordshow[40]; // a 40-char buffer should be large enough for %f
```

As a final note, `strlen` is designed to handle null-terminated character sequences (or strings). So, if you intend to use this function strictly for null-terminated strings, then this is fine. Otherwise, you may find it more appropriate to pass along the length of the buffer that you wish to write (something like `SD_write_to_file(const char* buff, int bufferLength)`).

Comment: Thanks my friend. now the writing to file is ok. But what it writes is not my float numbers . it is something like:  http://prntscr.com/4lnklm

I changed my code like this :  http://prntscr.com/4lnkyc

FYI my float numbers are starting from -4.9999 up to 4.9999.

Comment: Are you sure all numbers are indeed limited to that range (I updated my answer to include enough buffer space to handle extreme transient values)? Also, make sure `realSamples` is large enough to hold all the samples (ie. that there are no overflow when writing to `realSamples`).

Comment: Hi again. the problem was with sprintf function. I wrote my own function to copy each float number to tempwordshow array.  then the problem solved with your modification . thanks my friend. I post the solution in a new post . so everybody can use it in future :)

Answer (score 0):

SleuthEye was right. but after those modification I still couln`t write the correct float number in the file. some crap were written in the text file.

So I wrote my own function for converting float to string and the problem solved.
you need to do all the modification that SleuthEye mentioned above. additionally, use this function for changing type:

```
/** Number on countu**/

 int n_tu(int number, int count)
{
 int result=1;
 while(count-- > 0)
 result *=number;  

 return result;
 }
```

/***Convert float to string***/

```
void float_to_string(float f, char r[])
{
long long int length, length2, i, number, position, sign;
float number2;

sign=-1;   // -1 == positive number
if (f <0)
    {
    sign='-';
    f *= -1;    
    }   


number2=f;  
number=f;
length=0;  // size of decimal part
length2=0; //  size of tenth


/* calculate length2 tenth part*/
while( (number2 - (float)number) != 0.0 && !((number2 - (float)number) < 0.0) )
    {

    number2= f * (n_tu(10.0,length2+1));
    number=number2; 

    length2++;

    }

 /* calculate length decimal part*/
for(length=(f> 1) ? 0 : 1; f > 1; length++) 
  f /= 10;


 position=length;
 length=length+1+length2;
 number=number2;
 if(sign=='-')
     {
     length++;
     position++;
     }

 for(i=length; i >= 0 ; i--)
     {
    if(i== (length))
      r[i]='\0';
    else if(i==(position))
      r[i]='.';
    else if(sign=='-' && i==0)
      r[i]='-';
    else  
        {
          r[i]= (number % 10)+'0';
          number /=10;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks again . hope that it helps the others in future.  :)